# RxSwift Custom DataType Convertion without Binders

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Im new to RxSwift and working on with one of the application.
I had come across an issue where in my viewModel i get a custom DriverType(because of my algorithms or function calls which i needed in my case), 
say : `Driver<MyOwnObjectType>`. Now i want to convert this to `MyOwnObjectType`. I know i can do this by having the binders in the respective viewcontroller, like  below ex:

```
    fileprivate var testing: Binder<MyOwnObjectType> {
       return self.rx.selfBinder {_self, _value in
       // value is the actual MyOwnObjectType
       // Can i able to return this value?
      }
    }
```

But now i want to avoid the above , just wanted to retrieve the value `MyOwnObjectType`, or is there any way to bind using some method and return the value we bind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very poor practice and really should be avoided.

That said, if you really need it while refactoring to full RxSwift, you can bind to a BehaviorRelay and then use `.value` to get the current value out.

Comment: Ok @Daniel, let me try this out.